# Huge difference between in accuracy between model.evaluate and model.predict for tensorflow CNN model

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I am using ImageDataGenerator(validation_split).flow_from_directory(subset) for my training and validation sets. So the training and validation data get their own generators.

After training my data, I run model.evaluate() on my validation generator and got about 75% accuracy. However, when I run model.predict() on that same validation generator, the accuracy falls to 1%.

The model is a multiclass CNN compiled on categorical crossentropy loss and accuracy metrics, which should default to categorical accuracy. # Edit: changed to categorical accuracy anyways.

```
# Compile

learning_rate = tf.keras.optimizers.schedules.PolynomialDecay(initial_learning_rate=initial_lr,
                                                              decay_steps=steps,
                                                              end_learning_rate=end_lr)

model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.RMSprop(learning_rate),
              loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['categorical_accuracy'])

# Validation set evaluation

val_loss, val_accuracy = model.evaluate(val_generator,
                                        steps=int(val_size/bs)+1)
print('Accuracy: {}'.format(val_accuracy))

# Validation set predict

y_val = val_generator.classes

pred = model.predict(val_generator,
                     verbose=1
                     steps=int(val_size/bs)+1)

accuracy_TTA = np.mean(np.equal(y_val, np.argmax(pred, axis=-1)))
print('Accuracy: {}'.format(accuracy_TTA))
```

Comment: Could you update your question with the `model.compile()` statement, in particular, the losses and metrics

Comment: @strider0160 done

Comment: Not sure how your generator works but are you sure that the classes between `y_val` and the images used in the `model.predict` line up correctly?

Comment: @MZ i use the ImageDataGenerator class with the flow_from_directory method. The shuffle parameter is false. When I do check each image prediction separately it seems that the model.predict accuracy is more likely though. Not sure why that is the case.

Comment: @IsaacNg I've never really used the ImageDataGenerator the same way you have, but I would try to make sure that your class labels used for calculating `pred` are the same as `y_val`, and that they indeed line up. Could you do something like `x_val, y_val = next(val_generator)`?

Comment: @MZ The y_val values all all in order by class. Anyways I don't get the error anymore. I think it has something to do with having two separate generator instances.

Comment: @MZ Each ImageDataGenerator feeds to train_gen and val_gen respectively. They get the same seed but different subset parameters, 'training' and 'validation'.

The training one gets all the augmentations while the validation one just gets the rescale parameter.

Might have to do with the augmentations or the separate instances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with the varied accuracy values from model.evaluate and model.predict seems to be solved by creating separate instances of ImageDataGenerator() but with the same seed.

Also, sometimes during training KeyInterrupts or loading checkpoints, the generator instance should be reinitialised as the problem may occur.